# Problem with SSL certificate on Android 4.4: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, ssl

I do know why but my app on Android 4.4 (HTC 626) couldn't connect to my site. The problem occurs and from the app using URLConnection and OkHttpClient and when I try to open a site in Chrome ("Connection is not private").

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Certificate issued by Sectigo. SSL Checker doesn't show problems with a certificate on the server. The problem does not occur on Android 9 (Samsung A50). I suppose to try another CA. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by replacing the Comodo (Sectigo) Positive SL with the Thawte SSL123. It is not advertising. Both certificates were installed by one specialist, so I do not think there was wrong nginx configuration.